# How to force .htaccess used for routing to not route .css, .js, .jpg, etc. files?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have the following .htaccess file in a *subdirectory* of a site which allows me to route all URLs to index.php where I can parse them.

However, it's not allowing the standard files that I need for the website, e.g. css, javascript, pngs, etc.

What do I need to change (I assume in the fourth line) to allow these files so they don't get routed to index.php?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|css|js|png|jpg|gif|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/params=$1 [L,QSA]
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

Comment: Since you have the  `!-f` rule - if the request is being redirected at all, it doesn't match a file on disk, I.e. its a 4oh4 anyway.

Comment: Do you need to inherit anything from the main `.htaccess` file, assuming there is one in the root folder as well, or do you want this one to overwrite the other?

Comment: @AbsoluteZERO, this .htaccess file should overwrite anything above it, if possible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Something I noticed. You're using the forward slash instead of a question mark... the params redirect would normally look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?params=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This should work by itself since any of those files *should* be real files.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php    

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?params=$1 [L,QSA]
```

To have the site ignore specific extensions you can add a condition to ignore case and only check the end of the filenames in the request:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?params=$1 [L,QSA]
```

If you're trying to ignore a folder then you could add:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(public|css)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?params=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: With all these examples the index.php gets all the URL calls, so that works fine, but the site only looks good for e.g. "http://localhost/siteurl" and "http://localhost/siteurl/one", but for "http://localhost/siteurl/one/two" or "http://localhost/siteurl/one/two/three" the site has all broken CSS files and images. How can I fix that?

Comment: Thanks for this answer which solved the problem asked in this question but led to another problem which I describe here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063235/how-can-i-redirect-url-routing-without-breaking-links-to-css-js-images-after-two

Answer (score 7):

The easiest is to ignore them explicitly early in your rules:

```
RewriteRule \.(css|js|png|jpg|gif)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(index\.php|robots\.txt)$ - [L]
```

This avoid carrying them around all over the place with RewriteCond.

At your option, check that the file exists prior to doing so:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule \.(css|js|png|jpg|gif)$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(index\.php|robots\.txt)$ - [L]
```

(Note that the file check generates an extra disk access.)

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea, tweaking the fourth line.
The `^` is saying the various matching strings must be at the beginning of the line. If you don't care where any of these appear in the file, you can just remove the `^`. That will avoid rewriting *.css, *.js, etc.; but will also not rewrite publicideas.html.

If you want to limit to just the suffixes, try this:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|.*\.css|.*\.js|.*\.png|.*\.jpg|.*\.gif|robots\.txt)$
```

This says to match anything at the beginning, then a `.`, then the suffix. The `$` says match these at the end (nothing following).

I'm not sure about the `public`, so I left it (which means exactly public, with nothing else - probably not what you meant, but you can add a `*` before or after, or both).

Comment: I get an error 500 on all pages when I replace the fourth line with the one above, even if I change the first line to "RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|*\.css)$" I get an error 500.

Comment: @EdwardTanguay: see my reply to feeela's answer and my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` alone should be enough.

Another option is t exclude specific files from the rewrite.
From the TYPO3 packages:

```
# Stop rewrite processing, if we are in the typo3/ directory.
# For httpd.conf, use this line instead of the next one:
# RewriteRule ^/TYPO3root/(typo3/|t3lib/|fileadmin/|typo3conf/|typo3temp/|uploads/|favicon\.ico) - [L]
RewriteRule ^(typo3/|t3lib/|fileadmin/|typo3conf/|typo3temp/|uploads/|favicon\.ico) - [L]
```

This rule should appear before your actual rewrite. It should be

```
RewriteRule ^(public/|*\.css|*\.js|*\.png|*\.jpg|*\.gif|robots\.txt) - [L]
```

in your case.

Comment: @Denis Would you be so kind to tell me which one. I guess I'm tired.