# how to rename URL with htaccess without affecting on the relative links in the page

Tags: html, .htaccess, url

I tried to add this expression in htaccess file

```
footerrelated   ^help/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    index.php?requestedPage=footerrelated&page=$1 [NC,L]
```

so when the user enters a link like

```
http://localhost/askRondWebsite/public_html/footerrelated/helpcenter
```

it should return to

```
http://localhost/askRondWebsite/public_html/index.php?requestedPage=footerrelated&page=helpcenter
```

but this causes a problem with the relative links in the page.

For example, In my page I have the following `link` tag

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fotterrelated.css">
```

that refers to `http://localhost/askRondWebsite/public_html/css/fotterrelated.css`.

But when I add the`htaccess` expression the link refers to `http://localhost/askRondWebsite/public_html/fotterrelated/css/fotterrelated.css` .
and this happens with all the relative URLs in my website even when there is no created folder with the name `fotterrelated` in `public_html` folder.

Why is that happening? and what should I do to keep the relative URL as it was before adding the htaccess expression?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to force .htaccess used for routing to not route .css, .js, .jpg, etc. files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027747/how-to-force-htaccess-used-for-routing-to-not-route-css-js-jpg-etc-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this in the `<head>` section of your page's HTML:

```
<base href="/askRondWebsite/public_html/" />
```

so that every **relative URL** is resolved from that base URL and not from the current page's URL.