# htaccess with Angular and Phalcon

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, phalcon

I'm trying to switch the frontend of my Phalcon app to AngularJS. I'm having some troubles with the `.htaccess` file though. Below is what I currently have.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^api/.* api/index.php [L,QSA]

RewriteCond $1 !^(api)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
```

It routes to Phalcon, but all the `.css` and `.js` files in the public folder now throw a `404`. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore files and directories you need to add extra rewrite rules to your .htaccess. if you want to ignore extensions as well, there's another rewrite rule for that.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17029882 will give you the information you need. In your case

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif)$ [NC]`

is enough and in most cases also the files and directories are not rewritten with this:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`